# Regularity theorem for PDE: $-\Delta u \in C(\overline{\Omega})$ implies $u\in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I stumbled over this question in the context of PDE theory:
Let $U$ be connected,open and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u \in C^0(\overline{U}) \cap C^2(U)$ and $\Delta u \in C^0(\overline{U})$ with $u|_{\partial U} = \Delta u|_{\partial U} = 0.$ Does this imply that $u \in C^1(\overline{U})$?

Comment: Doesn't that follow from elliptic regularity? (That isn't rhetorical; I'm drawing a blank on the exact hypotheses of it.)

Comment: Actually I am not an expert on PDE theory and therefore I don't know to what exactly you are referring to.

Comment: The elliptic regularity theorem states that, under conditions I don't remember, a function $u$ with $Lu = f$ for some elliptic operator $L$ (e.g., $\Delta$) is in $C^k$ if $f$ is. It comes up, for example, in the Hodge theorem for de Rham cohomology.

Comment: thanks, I will adjust the title of this question accordingly. Hodge de Rham is far beyond this question ( introductory PDE course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U$ is a bounded domain with regular boundary then, one approach is the following: Consider the problem

$$
 \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
 -\Delta u=f &\mbox{ in}\  U, \\
  u=0 &\mbox{on } \partial U.
       \end{array} \right.
$$

Once $f\in C(\overline{U})$, we also have that $f\in L^p(U)$ for each $p\in [1,\infty)$. This implies in particular (see [1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540411607) chapter 9) that $u\in W_0^{2,p}(U)$ for each $p\in [1,\infty)$.

Now take $p$ big enough to conclude that $W_0^{2,p}(U)$ is continuously embedded in $C^1(\overline{U})$.